# What is the exception specification for a defaulted move operation defined outside the class?

Tags: c++11, standards, move, exception-specification

Consider this class:

```
class C1 {
  C1(C1&&) = default;        // declare and define move ctor
};
```

Because C1's move ctor is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, 8.4.2 of the Standard tells us it has the same exception specification (ES) as if the function had been implicitly declared. We can then use 15.4/14 and 12.8/15 to conclude that its ES is `noexcept(true)`.

Now consider a class C2 that is the same, except its move ctor is defaulted outside the class definition:

```
class C2 {
  C2(C2&&);                 // declare move ctor
}; 

C2::C2(C2&&) = default;     // define move ctor
```

What is the ES for C2's move ctor? Because it's not defaulted on its first declaration, 8.4.2/2 doesn't apply. Because it doesn't have an explicit ES, 8.4.2/3 doesn't apply. Because it's not implicitly declared, 15.4/14 doesn't apply. From what I can tell, that means that 15.4/12 applies, and it says that the default function ES is `noexcept(false)`.

If I'm right, that means that the move ctor in C1 is `noexcept(true)`, but the conceptually identical move ctor in C2 is `noexcept(false)`.

Is my reasoning about C2 correct?

Comment: looking at the [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf), I don't see where it specifies that it needs to be defaulted on the **first declaration**. Mind elaborating on this?

Comment: Check 8.4.2/2 and 8.4.2/3 of the C++14 spec.

Comment: The difference between the two is that `C2::C2(C2&&) = default;` could be in a different translation unit (and in fact, must be in exactly one translation unit). Code that only sees `C2(C2&&);` declaration has no choice but to assume the worst. On the other hand, the definition of `C1` must be repeated in full in every translation unit (under ODR), so anyone using it can independently conclude the constructor doesn't throw.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It sounds like you believe my interpretation is correct. Yes?

Comment: Yes, I believe your interpretation is correct, except for the "conceptually identical" part. That's the part I attempted to clarify - the two cases demonstrate a significant difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct, and if you make your declarations public, it is easy to show that both clang and gcc agree with your reasoning:

```
#include <type_traits>

class C1
{
public:
  C1(C1&&) = default;        // declare and define move ctor
};

class C2 {
public:
  C2(C2&&);                 // declare move ctor
}; 

C2::C2(C2&&) = default;     // define move ctor

int
main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<C1>{}, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<C2>{}, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation is correct, yes. Defaulting after the first declaration means generating the function body without performing any magic on the declaration. If the definition is in a different translation unit, you can freely switch between

```
C2::C2(C2&& rhs) {/* hand-written implementation here */}
```

and

```
C2::C2(C2&& rhs) = default;
```

and that is not visible to the users of the class. Since you didn't default
on the first declaration, the declaration is effectively noexcept(false) and (for better or worse) stays that way regardless of the subobjects in your class. Defaulting on the first declaration kicks in further "magic" in that
the noexcept-specification of your declaration can also be generated.

Comment: ah, except that even a special member function defaulted after its first declaration (aka outside the class definition) must match the implicit definition with regards to the noexcept-specification.